# Keeping only certain rows in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a dataset in Stata that looks like

```
Id | Var1 
------------------
1  | AMD  
1  | AMM  
1  | AMM
2  | AMM
3  | AMD
3  | AMD
4  | AMM
4  | AMM
```

I want to keep only the rows referred to the IDs that have at least one AMD. In this example, I want to get

```
 Id | Var1 
 ------------------
 1  | AMD  
 1  | AMM  
 1  | AMM
 3  | AMD
 3  | AMD
```

Comment: Have you tried anything specific? Can you show any research effort?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to Stata and I have no idea on how to solve this.

Comment: No need to apologize. But being new to Stata only reinforces tha fact that you must do research. I will point to `help by`, `help keep`, and `help subscripting`. On strategy is to create a binary variable that takes value equal to `1` if `Var1` equals `AMD`, and `0` otherwise. Then use `by` and `keep` (or `drop`) to keep groups that have at least one `1` value for the binary variable.

Comment: To underline @Roberto Ferrer's excellent advice, note for example that a criterion for downvoting is "does not show any research effort".

Comment: In Stata rows are called **observations**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from the question that `Var1` can contain only `AMD AMM`. If so, a complete solution is

```
bysort Id (Var1): keep if Var1[1] == "AMD"
```

There is no need to create any other variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
gen amd=(Var1=="AMD")
egen B=total(amd==1), by(Id)
keep if B
```